# npm modules aren't showing up in EMCA2015 JS imports

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to build a mobile app using the [Microsoft Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/) in Nativescript. So I have installed the SDK from npm, like this:

```
$ npm install azure-mobile-apps-client --save
```

However, when I then try to reference the module like this:

```
import * as WindowsAzure from 'azure-mobile-apps-client';
```

I get a warning:

> Cannot find module 'azure-mobile-apps-client'

It is such a simple thing that I don't really know where I could have gone wrong, or indeed about how the path management works in this situation. What can I do to fix this?

[Here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Azure-Nativescript) is the full project on Github.

As noted in the comments, maybe I should add a Typings definition, although I am not sure whether that is necessary, as it is all written in JS?

Comment: You need typings for the `azure-mobile-apps-client` module, then it'll work!

Comment: @JKillian even though the azure client doesn't use TypeScript?

Comment: The name of the question I marked this as a duplicate of is annoyingly unclear, but the problem/solution is the same. As JKillian said, you need the type definitions installed for the compiler to resolve the module's name.

Comment: @JoeClay Ahh, I see - thanks! There seems to be a `azuremobileservicesclient dt     http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/                                           2016-03-17T12:06:54.000Z` when I search typings registry, but when I run `typings install azure-mobile-apps --save`, it gets a 404 error, am I doing that right.

Comment: Try `typings install azure-mobile-apps --save --ambient` - I think definitions from DefinitelyTyped (which is what the `dt` in the search means) require that flag to be found when installing.

Comment: Actually, if it's showing up as `azuremobileservicesclient` in the search, you'll probably have to do `typings install azuremobileservicesclient --save --ambient`. The import should still be the same in your code though!

Comment: @JoeClay I have run that and it installed correctly, but I am still facing the same issue... I have updated my repository in case that helps.

Comment: Hm, for whatever reason, the type definitions for `azuremobileservicesclient` have the exported module named as `WindowsAzure`, but that doesn't seem right to me, as that's not the module's name in the docs. You might have to edit line 105 in the type definition to change it to the right name (`azure-mobile-apps-client`). If that fixes it, I'd recommend filing a bug on DefinitelyTyped's Github, so they can fix it for everyone!

Comment: @JoeClay swesome - that did it!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -2):

I'm just guessing based on Google searches, but:

```
var WindowsAzure = require('azure-mobile-apps-client');
```

should work, based on this article:

http://docs.nativescript.org/start/getting-started

Comment: It's `import WindowsAzure = require('azure-mobile-apps-client');` to do it with the `require` syntax in TypeScript. That said, I'd recommend using the ES6 style imports, as they're more likely to keep being supported in the future.